# Expected Value of the Product of a R.V. and an indicator function

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

a R.V. X has the Expected Value E(X)=1. But what happens when we multiplicity that X with the indicator function? How can I show that E(X⋅_A) is a Probability measure?

As always I appreciate you taking time and help :)

Best, KingDingeling

Comment: X needs to be non negative. Then just verify the axioms of a probably measure.

Comment: Thank you :) Appreciate it! I managed to to that.